# bootrec.exe /fixmbr doesn't work after removing linux dual-boot

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

I wanted to remove Linux from my windows 10 MSI laptop since I never used it.

I followed [this](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-or-linux-after-dual-booting-508710422) guide up until step 5. I thought instead of using a windows recovery disk I could just go to advanced startup and use the troubleshoot from there. However when I was on the troubleshoot CMD  `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` gave the error: `the system cannot find the file specified` Is this perhaps because I did not use a recovery disk?

When I boot my laptop now it has a grub 2 prompt instead of the dual-boot option. I can still get into windows by pressing `F11` on boot and selecting windows boot manager.

Edit:

I used a USB recovery and got the same error.

Also the command `bootrec.exe /scanos` and `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd` return `Total identified windows installations: 0` which I don't understand.

Comment: It's more likely your not using MBR, if the machine came with, Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound oh okay, so what does that mean? I don't really understand much about dual-booting / linux.

Comment: Well, do you have an MBR or an EFI boot partition

Comment: No idea, how would I find out?